# Getting User Sid

Tags: c#, service, windows-identity, userprincipal

I'm writing a service and I am trying to get the logged in User's sid and for whatever reason it is not working.  It only returns {S-1-5-18}.  Yet if I create a quick console application, it works just fine.

I've tried 2 methods:

```
WindowsIdentity usr = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
return usr.User
```

as well as:

```
UserPrincipal.Current.Sid
```

They both have the same affect in my service.  They both only return {S-1-5-18}.  Yet in a console app, they both return the full user sid.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are running your service-process as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` or `.\LOCALSYSTEM`.
Please see [KB 243330](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330) for more detail:

> SID: S-1-5-18
>   Name: Local System
>   Description: A service account that is used by the operating system.

If you want to get the SID from the desktop-session, you could eg go for (by utilizing [cassia](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/) - [nuget-package available](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Cassia)) :

```
    ITerminalServicesSession GetActiveSession()
    {
        var terminalServicesSession = default(ITerminalServicesSession);
        var terminalServicesManager = new TerminalServicesManager();
        using (var server = terminalServicesManager.GetLocalServer())
        {
            foreach (var session in server.GetSessions())
            {
                if (session.ConnectionState == ConnectionState.Active)
                {
                    // yep, I know ... LINQ ... but this is from a plain .NET 2.0 source ...
                    terminalServicesSession = session;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return terminalServicesSession;
    }
```

The `ITerminalServiceSession`-instance does contain the property `SessionId` which should work as needed. But please, be aware that there are caveats associated with state of the session - I do not guarantee that my condition suffices, you may need to adapt the condition on `ConnectionState` as needed.

Comment: I set up the service using a hidden form and message pump so that I could capture logged user's activity.  It is doing that successfully as far as computer locks, unlocks, logons, etc.  I assumed because that was working, it would be pulling their sid as well.  Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: @FLAdmin please see my edit - I've added a demo for utilizing cassia to query the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Those APIs will return the SID of the user executing the current process, in your case your service. `S-1-5-18` is `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

There can be anything from zero to many users logged on to a Windows system (for interactive use: either locally or remotely): there is no singular "logged on user".

You need to refine your requirements: why do you want to know the logged on user?